# Unexpected behaviour of "lui a4,%hi(0x0001ff00)"

Tags: compiler-errors, cross-compiling, gnu, riscv

I have problems with the `%hi()` assembler function.
This question is specific to the RISC-V GNU assembler. Compiling this program:

```
lui     a4,%hi(0x0001ff00)     # Does not give what I expect
lui     a4,0x1f                #
.word   0x0001f737             #
```

with

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-as  -o strange_lui.o strange_lui.s
riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -D strange_lui.o
```

give

```
strange_lui.o:     file format elf32-littleriscv
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000 <.text>:
0:  00020737            lui a4,0x20
4:  0001f737            lui a4,0x1f
8:  0001f737            lui a4,0x1f
```

I would have believed these three lines should compile to the same code. So what am I missing here? I'm using:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-as  -v
GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (riscv32-unknown-elf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.31.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%hi(...)` function is cleverer than it looks.  It doesn't just return the top 20 bits of the given argument.

`%hi` expects to be used in a `lui` instruction that will shortly be followed by another instruction like `add %lo(...)`, which will complete a 32-bit load of the register by providing the low 12 bits.

During the execution of the `add` instruction those low 12 bits will be sign-extended to produce a 32-bit value, which is then added to the original content of the register.  When the top bit of the low 12 is a 0 this sign-extension step has no effect on the existing top 20 bits of the register.  However, when the top bit of the low 12 is a '1' the sign-extension has the effect of subtracting one from the existing value of the register's upper 20 bits.

In this case the `%hi(0x0001ff00)` function sees that the leftmost bit of the lower 12 is a '1'.  It therefore anticipates the subtraction that would be performed by a following `add %lo(0x0001ff00)` and writes `0x00020` into the top 20 bits of the register.  That `0x00020` would be converted into your desired `0001f` by the expected sign-extended `add`.

If you want your program to generate the same instruction for all three statements, give `%hi` an argument whose low 12 bits have a 0 in their leftmost position.  Something like `lui %hi(0x0001f700)` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In summary the "%hi()" macro assumes a signed int value if used with the signed value returned by "%lo()".

I don't even think that the "lui" instruction is even assumed, this could be any other instruction taking immediate values. It's what you use in your sample, but there are many other RV instructions that use immediate parameters

So there should be another form, like "%hu()", to be used with "%lu()", to not assume this sign extension of the low part and not even assuming that "%lu()" will be used